# ¿Como obtener los valores mediante startAt y endAt, mediante una propiedad combinada, firebase?

Tags: firebase, timestamp

Tengo una propiedad combinada llamada: `usuario_fecha`en la cual guardo el id+la fecha en timestamp de la siguiente forma:

```
"-Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA1556016094000"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta la estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma:

```
            let vm = this;
            let fechaInicio = new Date(this.fechaInicio);
            fechaInicio.setHours(0,0,0,0)
            let fechaFin = new Date(this.fechaFin);
            fechaFin.setHours(23,59,59,999);

            console.log("STARTAT");
            console.log(vm.producto_id+fechaInicio.getTime());
            console.log("ENDAT");
            console.log(vm.producto_id+fechaFin.getTime());

            firebase
              .database()
              .ref('movimientos_inventario')
              .orderByChild('usuario_fecha')
              .startAt(vm.producto_id+fechaInicio.getTime())
              .endAt(vm.producto_id+fechaFin.getTime())
              .once('value', (snapshot) => {
                   console.log("MOVIMIENTOS INVENTARIO");
                    let filtrado = snapshot.val();
                    console.log(filtrado);
                    if(filtrado){
                        console.log("FILTRADO: ");
                        console.log(filtrado);
                    }
               });
```

La fecha en timestamp que estoy enviando basicamente esta bien, en consola me imprime los siguientes valores:

```
STARTAT
-Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA1554012000000
ENDAT
-Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA1555999199999
```

dentro de ese rango de fechas existe un registro pero la consulta en firebase no me lo esta devolviendo, no se cual pueda ser el problema.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Perdón, lo acabo de editar. El problema es que la consulta no me esta devolviendo ningun registro

Comment: Según la estructura que muestras no hay ningún nodo equivalente a `Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA1554012000000` ni equivalente a `Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA1555999199999`, a mi me parece que no estás entendiendo bien cómo funciona Firebase y que estás creando combinaciones irrecuperables. Aún en caso de que haya un nodo bajo la clave `Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA1555999199999` ¿cómo vas a determinar esa clave dentro de 1 semana o 1 mes para pasarla como criterio de búsqueda?

Comment: Entonces como podría realizar una consulta, en base al id 'Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA'  y en un rango de fechas obtener sus registros, es decir un query doble?

Comment: La documentación de Firebase explica muy bien cómo hacer consultas y cómo aplicar filtros `where`. La cuestión es que si tú otorgas a un nodo el identificador `Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA` generado por defecto, ¿cómo rayos vas a saber que es ese dato el que hay que buscar entre miles o millones de nodos? En Firebase tienes que plantearte muy bien cómo vas a estructurar los datos, pensando también en las formas en que tienes que consultarlos en el futuro.

Comment: Te comento el contexto, básicamente existe un nodo llamado: movimientos_inventario, y el identificador Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA, hace referencia a un objeto que se encuentro en un nodo llamado 'productos' en el nodo productos, cuando se crea el producto se registra mediante push() y ya en el nodo 'movimientos_inventario', solamente se replica este mismo objeto con su id. Entonces quiero obtener los movimientos_inventario en base al id del producto y un rango de fecha.

Comment: Estoy utilizando esto como ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

la opción 2 de la mejor respuesta.

Comment: Es precisamente lo que te estoy diciendo, si observas las referencias que se usan allí, se usan cosas entendibles como `comedy`, `Jack Nicholson`, etc. Cuando necesites buscar las comedias, o buscar algo de `Jack Nicholson` o de `Pepe`, sabes que se llaman así, pero ¿qué rayos es `Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA` aparte de una clave autogenerada?. Otra cosa es que digas, voy a buscar por `ProductoTal` o `ProductoCual`, ese sí es un dato que puedes conocer de antemano y buscar en base a él. La estructura de datos que presentas se hará insostenible cuando tengas cientos o miles de nodos.

Comment: pero -Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA,seria el id del producto. algo asi como lo que hace en el ejemplo de .startAt('comedy_1990')
  .endAt('comedy_2000')

Comment: No sé chico, cuando tengas miles de registros te quiero ver adivinando claves como `Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA` para hacer tus búsquedas. Cuando hablas de `comedy_1990` y `comedy_2000` se entiende claramente que se refiere a las comedias entre los años `1990` y `2000`, pero una búsqueda entre los rangos `Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA` y `Mz7R2gzHJCPaSdwsZMB` ¿a qué se refiere? Creo que debes pensar cómo estructurar los datos en base a lo que hace tu app, pensando también en la forma en que los consultarás en el futuro, cuando haya miles o millones de datos.

Comment: El rango seria con el mismo id, -Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA1554012000000 y -Ld6P2gzGIBOaSdwsYNA1555999199999

Comment: Esto : `comedy_1990` y `comedy_2000` se lee: *comedias entre 1990 y 2000*, ¿y lo tuyo, cómo se lee?

Comment: id del producto entre ese rango de fecha  1554012000000 y 1555999199999 (timestamp)